# Evaluating Sum of Infinite Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$a_n= \frac{1^1}{n^2} + \frac{2^1}{n^2}+\cdots+\frac{n^1}{n^2}$$

And I am given the hint $\sum_{i=1}^k i =\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$

Not really sure how to proceed here or what the hint has to do with this, I was thinking that $\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^1}{n^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ which diverges to $\infty$ but the answer is convergent.

Comment: You never said what the series is. Is $a_n$ the partial sum or the $n$th term? Or is that $S_n$?

Comment: $a_k=\frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{1}{k})$ and so the sum of this series will diverge as the sum of an infinite number of halves is already divergent...

Comment: Also, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ does not diverge to $\infty$

Comment: $\lim_n a_n$ is not an infinite series. The sum of an infinite series has the form $\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_1 + \cdots + a_n),$ where one new term is added each time $n$ increases by $1,$ but the terms that were already there do not change. Thus in an infinite series, as $n$ goes from $100$ to $101,$ the terms $a_1,a_2,a_3$ do not change. Nor $a_{100}.$ But in your expression, those terms do change as $n$ changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that$$a_n=\frac1{n^2}(1+2+3+\cdots+n)=\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}.$$So, $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\frac12$.